# PHP preg_split() pattern

Tags: php, pcre, preg-split

I need help finding a PCRE pattern using preg_split().

I'm using the regex pattern below to split a string based on its starting 3 character code and semi-colons. The pattern works fine in Javascript, but now I need to use the pattern in PHP. I tried preg_split() but just getting back junk.

// Each group will begin with a three letter code, have three segments separated by a semi-colon. The string will not be terminated with a semi-colon.

```
// Pseudocode    
string_to_split = "AAA;RED;111;BBB;BLUE;22;CCC;GREEN;33;DDD;WHITE;44"

// This works in JS  
// https://regex101.com  
$pattern = "/[AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD][^;]*;[^;]*[;][^;]*/gi";

Match 1  
Full match  0-11    `AAA;RED;111`  
Match 2  
Full match  12-23   `BBB;BLUE;22`  
Match 3  
Full match  24-36   `CCC;GREEN;33`  
Match 4  
Full match  37-49   `DDD;WHITE;44`  

$pattern = "/[AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD][^;]*;[^;]*[;][^;]*/";  
$split = preg_split($pattern, $string_to_split);

returns

array(5)  
    0:""  
    1:";"  
    2:";"  
    3:";"  
    4:""
```

Comment: `[AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD]` does not look as it would run in JS correctly. Did you mean `(AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD)`?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: `[AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD]` is the same thing as `[ABCD|]` and it means *"any character from inside the character class (i.e. between `[` and `]`)"*. What you want is `(AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD)` which means *"`AAA` or `BBB` or `CCC `or `DDD`"*.

Comment: @axiac, you can use a regex to split a string in JavaScript.

Comment: @fubar indeed, [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) accepts a `RegExp` as argument. However, the description of the requirement calls for matching, not splitting.

Comment: Thanks. This is helping me a lot. For clarification, a string may contain many groups of "AAA" or "BBB" etc. Here's an example. 
"AAA;RED;111;AAA;Oh my dog;2.34;AAA;Oh Long John;.4556;BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323;BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33;CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445;CCC;All the live long day;2.3343;DDD;Faith Hilling;.89" <--no ; at end of string. 

Result is an array. 

[0] AAA;RED;111; 
[1] AAA;Oh my dog;2.34; 
[2] AAA;Oh Long John;.4556; 
[3] BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323; 
[4] BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33;
[5] CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445;
[6] CCC;All the live long day;2.3343;
[7] DDD;Faith Hilling;.89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to split your string but match elements, use preg_match_all:

```
$str = "AAA;RED;111;AAA;Oh my dog;2.34;AAA;Oh Long John;.4556;BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323;BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33;CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445;CCC;All the live long day;2.3343;DDD;Faith Hilling;.89";
$res = preg_match_all('/(?:AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD);[^;]*;[^;]*;?/', $str, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => AAA;RED;111;
    [1] => AAA;Oh my dog;2.34;
    [2] => AAA;Oh Long John;.4556;
    [3] => BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323;
    [4] => BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33;
    [5] => CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445;
    [6] => CCC;All the live long day;2.3343;
    [7] => DDD;Faith Hilling;.89
)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                       : regex delimiter
  (?:AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD)   : non capture group AAA or BBB or CCC or DDD
  ;                     : a semicolon
  [^;]*                 : 0 or more any character that is not a semicolon
  ;                     : a semicolon
  [^;]*                 : 0 or more any character that is not a semicolon
  ;?                    : optional semicolon
/                       : regex delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks. The breakdown helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your pattern a little, and added a couple of flags to `preg_split`.

The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag will exclude empty matches from the result, and `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` will include the captured value in the result.

```
$split = preg_split('/([abcd]{3};[^;]+;\d+);?/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AAA;RED;111
    [1] => BBB;BLUE;22
    [2] => CCC;GREEN;33
    [3] => DDD;WHITE;44
)
```

Alternatively, and more suitably, you can use `preg_match_all` with the following pattern.

```
preg_match_all('/([abcd]{3};[^;]+;\d+);?/i', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AAA;RED;111
    [1] => BBB;BLUE;22
    [2] => CCC;GREEN;33
    [3] => DDD;WHITE;44
)
```

Comment: You got it. Thanks. I just needed to address the decimal.  

"AAA;RED;111;AAA;Oh my dog;2.34;AAA;Oh Long John;.4556;BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323;BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33;CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445;CCC;All the live long day;2.3343;DDD;Faith Hilling;.89";  

preg_split('/([AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD]{3};[^;]+;[0-9]\.[0-9]\d+);?/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)

0:"AAA;RED;111;"
1:"AAA;Oh my dog;2.34"
2:"AAA;Oh Long John;.4556;"
3:"BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323"
4:"BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33;"
5:"CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445"
6:"CCC;All the live long day;2.3343"
7:"DDD;Faith Hilling;.89"

Comment: So do you just need to match decimal values too? Or are there other issues?

Comment: `[a|b|c|d]{3}` is not propper. It is equivalent to `[abc|]` and as it turned out, it matches e.g. `"ab|"` or `"a|a"`. It is not completely clear if the questioner wants tripple-groups of "AAA" only or "ABC" as well. The examples suggest "AAA", "BBB" only. Nevertheless, the `|` is wrong at this place.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone - good call on the `|`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to your additional information in some comments to the answers, I update my answer to be very specific to your source format.

You might want something like this:

```
$subject = "AAA;RED;111;AAA;Oh my dog;12.34;AAA;Oh Long John;.4556;BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323;BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33;CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445;CCC;All the live long day;2.3343;DDD;Faith Hilling;.89";

$pattern = '/(?<=;|^)(AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD);([^;]*);((?:\d*\.)?\d+)(?=;|$)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

giving you

```
array (size=4)
  0 =>
    array (size=8)
      0 => string 'AAA;RED;111' (length=11)
      1 => string 'AAA;Oh my dog;12.34' (length=19)
      2 => string 'AAA;Oh Long John;.4556' (length=22)
      3 => string 'BBB;Oh Long Johnson;1.2323' (length=26)
      4 => string 'BBB;Oh Don Piano;.33' (length=20)
      5 => string 'CCC;Why I eyes ya;1.445' (length=23)
      6 => string 'CCC;All the live long day;2.3343' (length=32)
      7 => string 'DDD;Faith Hilling;.89' (length=21)
  1 =>
    array (size=8)
      0 => string 'AAA' (length=3)
      1 => string 'AAA' (length=3)
      2 => string 'AAA' (length=3)
      3 => string 'BBB' (length=3)
      4 => string 'BBB' (length=3)
      5 => string 'CCC' (length=3)
      6 => string 'CCC' (length=3)
      7 => string 'DDD' (length=3)
  2 =>
    array (size=8)
      0 => string 'RED' (length=3)
      1 => string 'Oh my dog' (length=9)
      2 => string 'Oh Long John' (length=12)
      3 => string 'Oh Long Johnson' (length=15)
      4 => string 'Oh Don Piano' (length=12)
      5 => string 'Why I eyes ya' (length=13)
      6 => string 'All the live long day' (length=21)
      7 => string 'Faith Hilling' (length=13)
  3 =>
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '111' (length=3)
      1 => string '12.34' (length=5)
      2 => string '.4556' (length=5)
      3 => string '1.2323' (length=6)
      4 => string '.33' (length=3)
      5 => string '1.445' (length=5)
      6 => string '2.3343' (length=6)
      7 => string '.89' (length=3)
```

The start marker should occur at the start of string or immidiately after a semicolon, so we do a lookbehind, looking for start or semicolon:

```
(?<=;|^)
```

We look for an alternative of AAA,BBB,CCC or DDD and capture it:

```
(AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD)
```

After a semicolon we look for any character except a semicolon. The quantifier `*` means 0 or more time. Use `+` if you want at least 1.

```
;([^;]*)
```

After the next semicolon wie look for a number. This task has to be splitted to fit a valid format: We first look for 0 or more digits followed by a dot:

```
(?:\d*\.)?
```

where `(?:)` means a non-capturing group.

Behind we look for at least one digit: `\d+`

We want to capture both parts of of the number using parentheses after the searched semicolon:

```
;((?:\d*\.)?\d+)
```

This matches "1234", ".1234", "1.234", "12.34" , "123.4" but "1234.", "1.2.3"

Finally we want this to immediately occur before a semicolon or the end of string. Thus we do a lookahead:

```
(?=;|$)
```

Lookaheads and lookbehinds are not part of the captured result behind or respectively before.

Comment: I tried this pattern "/[AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD]{3}(?:;[^;]*){2}/" but it didn't work.

Comment: This was not the expression I gave. I've updated my answer to be even more specific to your source format additionally given in your other comments.